# Problema en Python con un if dentro del bucle for

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un programa en Python, que básicamente trata de simular el juego del Hang Man o el Ahorcado(en español), y todo va bien excepto que cuando introduzco una palabra que sí es correcta, sustituye la rayita por la letra que introduje PERO igualmente te descuenta la vida a pesar de que lo programe para que no lo hiciera, he tratado de ver si tengo un error de como coloque las indentaciones pero no he encontrado donde está el error. Este es el código:

```
import random

palabras = ["AEROPUERTO", "SUIZA", "ITLA", "SOFTWARE", "WEB", "ADRIAN", "ADELE", "MAMBO"]
palabra_elegida = random.choice(palabras)
incognita = []
largo_palabra = len (palabra_elegida)
vidas = 6


print (palabra_elegida)

print ()
for caracter in range (largo_palabra):
    incognita += "_"
print (incognita)
print ()

while "_" in incognita:

    intento = input ("Introduzca una letra: ").upper()

    if intento == "SALIR":
        quit()


    for position in range (largo_palabra):
        letra = palabra_elegida [position] 
        if letra == intento:
            incognita[position] = letra
    if not letra == intento:
            vidas = vidas - 1
            print (f"You have failed, you have {vidas} lives.")
            if vidas == 0:
                print ("You have lost, try again, loser.")
                quit()
    
print (incognita) 


if not "_" in incognita:
    print ("Congratulations! You have won.")
    quit()
```

Comment: El segundo if está mal, con eso co pruebas si la última letra de la palabra elegida es igual a lo que ingreso el usuario. Para solucionar tu problema deberías usar un *flag* para saber si después de recorrer toda la palabra la letra no se encuentra. También puedes hacerlo de forma simple con el operador `in` de esta forma `if intento in palabra elegida: #código en caso la letra este else: #restas vida`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer error es que chequear si la posición en `incognita` ya está ocupada. Entonces, con palabras como "ADRIAN", la segunda 'A' no es reemplazada.

El código corregido es:

```
if letra == intento and incognita[position] == '_':
    incognita[position] = letra
    break
```

El segundo error es como detectas que la letra no está. La mejor manera es usar la variación `for - else`, que funciona de la siguiente manera:

- Si el `for` termina normalmente, se ejecuta el `else`.
- Si sales del `for` con un break, **no** se ejecuta el `else

Con eso puedo capturar la condición no "letra no encontrada", dejando el código así:

```
for position in range(largo_palabra):
    letra = palabra_elegida[position]
    if letra == intento and incognita[position] == '_':
        incognita[position] = letra
        break
else:
    vidas = vidas - 1
    print(f"You have failed, you have {vidas} lives.")
    if vidas == 0:
        print("You have lost, try again, loser.")
        quit()
```

#### Demo

ADRIAN

```
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']

Introduzca una letra: a
['A', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Introduzca una letra: d
['A', 'D', '_', '_', '_', '_']
Introduzca una letra: r
['A', 'D', 'R', '_', '_', '_']
Introduzca una letra: i
['A', 'D', 'R', 'I', '_', '_']
Introduzca una letra: a
['A', 'D', 'R', 'I', 'A', '_']
Introduzca una letra: n
['A', 'D', 'R', 'I', 'A', 'N']
Congratulations! You have won.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funciono!